# Log gamma integral with a slightly more complicated polynomial factor

Tags: integration, polygamma

I need some help figuring out how to evaluate this integral.

$$\frac{1}{n!}\int_0^1 (x-t)^n \ln\Gamma(t) \, dt$$

A similar integral is known due to the work of Victor Adamchik.  But I haven’t been able to figure out how to use it.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Binomial theorem will get you an answer in terms of moments of $\log{\Gamma(t).$  Wolfram alpha solves these in terms of the Glaisher-Kinkelin constant, and Riemann zeta (and its derivatives.)

Comment: This is just [Cauchy's repeated integral formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_formula_for_repeated_integration) applied to the log-gamma function. These can be written as [generalized polygamma functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balanced_polygamma_function) at negative values.